# Esper: StackOverflowError when moving patterns in/out isolated state in esper

Tags: java, esper

I wanted to initialized/updated pattern's state from historical data and often got StackOverflowError for some cases. I wrote simple example to demonstrate:

```
public class Main {
EsperPatternStackOverflow.zip
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
        configuration.addEventType("TestEvent", TestEvent.class);
        configuration.getEngineDefaults().getViewResources().setShareViews(false);
        configuration.getEngineDefaults().getExecution().setAllowIsolatedService(true);
        EPServiceProvider epService = EPServiceProviderManager.getDefaultProvider(configuration);
        epService.initialize();

        EPServiceProviderIsolated isolatedService = epService.getEPServiceIsolated("Isolated");
        EPStatement stmt = isolatedService.getEPAdministrator().createEPL("select * from pattern [every (a=TestEvent -> b=TestEvent(theString=a.theString)) where timer:within(1 day)]", "TestStatement",null);
        int hour_ms = 60*60*1000;
        isolatedService.getEPRuntime().sendEvent(new CurrentTimeEvent(System.currentTimeMillis()- 2*hour_ms));
        isolatedService.getEPRuntime().sendEvent(new TestEvent("str1", 1));
         stmt.addListener((newEvents, oldEvents) -> {
            System.out.println("Fired");
        });
        isolatedService.getEPAdministrator().removeStatement(stmt);
        epService.getEPRuntime().sendEvent(new TestEvent("str1", 3));
    }
}
```

TestEvent is a simple class with two fields: int theInt, String theString.

Result:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
        at com.espertech.esper.filter.FilterParamIndexEquals.matchEvent(FilterParamIndexEquals.java:29)
        at com.espertech.esper.filter.FilterHandleSetNode.matchEvent(FilterHandleSetNode.java:99)
        at com.espertech.esper.filter.EventTypeIndex.matchType(EventTypeIndex.java:170)
        at com.espertech.esper.filter.EventTypeIndex.matchEvent(EventTypeIndex.java:108)
        at com.espertech.esper.filter.FilterServiceBase.retryableMatchEvent(FilterServiceBase.java:179)
        at com.espertech.esper.filter.FilterServiceBase.evaluateInternal(FilterServiceBase.java:109)
        at com.espertech.esper.filter.FilterServiceLockCoarse.evaluate(FilterServiceLockCoarse.java:67)
        at com.espertech.esper.core.service.EPRuntimeImpl.handleFilterFault(EPRuntimeImpl.java:1267)
        at com.espertech.esper.core.service.EPRuntimeImpl.processStatementFilterSingle(EPRuntimeImpl.java:1242)
        at com.espertech.esper.core.service.EPRuntimeImpl.handleFilterFault(EPRuntimeImpl.java:1271)
        at com.espertech.esper.core.service.EPRuntimeImpl.processStatementFilterSingle(EPRuntimeImpl.java:1242)
.......................................................................................................................................................................
```

Also I got the next exception for similar cases (differ only in top point of exception):

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
        at com.espertech.esper.event.bean.CGLibPropertyGetter.get(CGLibPropertyGetter.java:63)
        at com.espertech.esper.filter.FilterParamIndexEquals.matchEvent(FilterParamIndexEquals.java:29)
        at com.espertech.esper.filter.FilterHandleSetNode.matchEvent(FilterHandleSetNode.java:99)
        at com.espertech.esper.filter.EventTypeIndex.matchType(EventTypeIndex.java:170)
        at com.espertech.esper.filter.EventTypeIndex.matchEvent(EventTypeIndex.java:108)
        at com.espertech.esper.filter.FilterServiceBase.retryableMatchEvent(FilterServiceBase.java:179)
        at com.espertech.esper.filter.FilterServiceBase.evaluateInternal(FilterServiceBase.java:109)
        at com.espertech.esper.filter.FilterServiceLockCoarse.evaluate(FilterServiceLockCoarse.java:67)
        at com.espertech.esper.core.service.EPRuntimeImpl.handleFilterFault(EPRuntimeImpl.java:1267)
        at com.espertech.esper.core.service.EPRuntimeImpl.processStatementFilterSingle(EPRuntimeImpl.java:1242)
        at com.espertech.esper.core.service.EPRuntimeImpl.handleFilterFault(EPRuntimeImpl.java:1271)
        at com.espertech.esper.core.service.EPRuntimeImpl.processStatementFilterSingle(EPRuntimeImpl.java:1242)
......................................................................................................................................................................
```

Why this exception is thrown and how can I solve this issue?
Thanks.

Comment: You should provide the complete stack trace.

Comment: All rows below is
..........................................
 at com.espertech.esper.core.service.EPRuntimeImpl.handleFilterFault(EPRuntimeImpl.java:1271)
 at com.espertech.esper.core.service.EPRuntimeImpl.processStatementFilterSingle(EPRuntimeImpl.java:1242)
 at com.espertech.esper.core.service.EPRuntimeImpl.handleFilterFault(EPRuntimeImpl.java:1271)
 at com.espertech.esper.core.service.EPRuntimeImpl.processStatementFilterSingle(EPRuntimeImpl.java:1242)
 at com.espertech.esper.core.service.EPRuntimeImpl.handleFilterFault(EPRuntimeImpl.java:1271)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed in version 5.5.0

From changelog (https://github.com/espertechinc/esper/blob/master/changelog.txt):

Bug fixes
  - Fixed issue ESC-000-00001 stack overflow creating isolated pattern statement, partially completing pattern and un-isolating stmt